# Activity logs on users roles and permissions in magento

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new to magento and I really have a lot to learn on it, I want to ask two qeustions, 
1. Where can I get a developers video on magento, I have searched everywhere on the internet, but to no avail.
2. I want to make an activity log at the backend of magento so that the Admin can see what other users are doing and when they do it, What I mean is the Admin monitors other backend users
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have magento tutorials from here
http://code.tutsplus.com/categories/magento

The next thing you want to do , is built custom module for this. Magento by default have no such feature, The tutorial might help you for your task